# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: "Видимо(,) просмотр разрешен только россиянам." (речь об отображении картинки в интернете). Нужна ли запятая после "видимо", а то я уже путаюсь, где вводные слова, а где нет))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна. *Видимо* в данном случае вводное слово, оно грамматически не связано с другими словами.